# jQuery overflow works only after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, coverflow

I'm using jQuery overflow effect (http://vanderlee.github.io/coverflow/) on a website (http://www.assetrisk.ch). Unfortunately the pictures on first loading the site are a wrong distance from left. After a reload everything is fine.

the code is

```
$('#preview-coverflow').coverflow({
    select: function(event, cover, index) {
        var rel = $("#c"+index).attr('rel');
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/assets/ajax/inc.ajax.php",
            data: { objid: rel }
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            $('.dyn-inhalt').html(msg);
            //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
    }
});
```

Any tips/help

thanks 
thomas

Comment: did you try it inside $(function () { ... your code ... });

Comment: Yes, it is already inside $(function() {  ... });